# What does SELECT ... PROCEDURE procedure_name do?

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

In reading through the documentation, I noticed that MySQL's `SELECT` syntax has a clause that I had never really caught before:

> ```
> SELECT
>    ...
>    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
>    ...
> ```

I am intrigued, since from what little I could understand from their [terse explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm139957749977696) and their [example with `PROCEDURE ANALYSE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html), one can pass data (and possibly metadata as well?) from a `SELECT` statement into a stored procedure. However, searching elsewhere for more details didn't yield any results, and the source for the `ANALYSE` procedure proved elusive to `SHOW PROCEDURE` calls in every database.

I ask more out of curiosity, since I know nothing about it, but what is this clause for, and what can I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation by 
Morgan Tocker (MySQL Community Manager)

http://www.tocker.ca/2015/06/29/plan-to-deprecate-procedure-analyse.html

Comment: Nice find! Strange that the most informative article on the should come in 2015 when the feature itself was implemented before stored procedures even existed!